# javascript XMLHttpRequest open php file and execute more javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, httprequest, activexobject

I have a main page, call it Main.php.  On this page, is a button that when clicked, sets a div's innerHTML (already on Main.php, called divResults) with the results from Results.php.

When Results.php is called, the returned HTML "These Are The Results" is properly received and set as the contents to divResults on Main.php.  However, any javascript from Results.php is not executed. As an example, I attempt to do a simple window.alert. Here is example code:

Main.php link button to begin the action:

```
<img src="$MyImageSource" onclick=\"ExpandDropdownDiv()\" />
```

Main.php javascript function ExpandDropdownDiv():

```
function ExpandDropdownDiv(){

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)/* code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari */
    {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {/* code for IE6, IE5 */
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)/* && xmlhttp.status==200) */
        {
            document.getElementById("divResults").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","Results.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();

}
```

Results.php code example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Success");
</script>
These Are The Results
```

**------------------ Edit - Update ------------------**

The simple alert, from Results.php is just an example.  If I were able to get this to work, I believe I could solve the rest of my problem on my own.  However, I noticed a few comments suggesting to just place the alert in Main.php's javascript after i set the div's innerHTML.  So, let me explain what I truly want to do with the javascript, after the div is set.

**Image 1**, shows some normal "Select" html elements, that have been transformed using jquery and the dropdown-check-list extension (.js).  When the user clicks the colorful down arrow at the bottom, the div expands, **(image 2)** and two more "Select" elements are generated within this other .php file... the html is returned, and placed in the div.  Thus, i do not need to reload the entire page, and can place the new select dropdowns just beneath the existing ones.

The problem is, to "transform" these normal select elements, there is some javascript that needs to be executed against that HTML:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $(".MultiSelect").dropdownchecklist(  {firstItemChecksAll: true, maxDropHeight: 300 , searchTextbox: true, width: 100, textFormatFunction: function(options) {
        var selectedOptions = options.filter(":selected");
        var countOfSelected = selectedOptions.size();
        var size = options.size();
        switch(countOfSelected) {
        case 0: return "All";
        case 1: return selectedOptions.text();
/*      case size: return "All"; */
        default: return countOfSelected + " selected";
        }
    } 
    }
    ); 
}
```

So, somehow I need to be able to execute javascript against the HTML that is generated from this other .php file.  And simply calling the above code, after my divs innerHTML is filled, only re-generates the already existing dropdowns, not the two new ones.

**Example Images**

[image]

[image]

Comment: why not just put the alert("Success'); inside ajax callback?

Comment: @kjy112 - can you give me an example i will try? i barely got this code to work and dont even fully understand it.

Comment: The easiest way to go about it Adam is to not embed the javascript within your PHP, but instead perform the JavaScript after you inject the php result in the ajax callback function.

Comment: @Adam if u just want to get it up and running just look at the Easy Part under my answer

Comment: @kjy - your answer was VERY easy to read and understand, for that i thank you very much!  i tried your example though, and still got the error that result was undfined... =[

Comment: @Adam i think i understand what you attempt to accomplish. what i would do personally is use the php to retrive vendor and class information, and once ajax callsback, create the textarea and labels Elements, inject retrived data for vendor and class into them, and inject it into the DOM. all these would be done on client-side after `document.getElementById("divResults").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;`.

Comment: trying to read & understand what DOM manipulation/injection is and how its done.  but using what you said, i think i can make it work... i also think maybe i could create the dropdowns, but just have the div display:none... once i get the data for the dropdowns / select elements, fill them with the returned data, and set the div to be visible.  One question though, is the innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText when the Ajax "Calls back"? or is that a different line of code?    I appreicate the help kjy, thank you so much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a good read on understanding what you are doing: [Eval embed JavaScript Ajax: YUI style](http://blog.fredrikbostrom.net/2008/10/29/executing-embedded-javascript-after-ajax-call)

**Making your code work with using eval(); but its not recommend for various reasons:**

Let's take your php and modify it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function result() {
        alert("Success");
    }
</script>
These Are The Results
```

and This is the callback function from AJAX. result(); is not executed because it doesn't get evaluated, and thus does not exist.  which is in your case

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)/* && xmlhttp.status==200) */
        {
            document.getElementById("divResults").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            result(); // this function is embedded in the responseText
                      // and doesn't get evaluated. I.e. it doesn't exist
}
```

in order for the browser to recognize the `result();` you must do an `eval();` on all the JavaScript statements with in the script tags that you injected into the div with `id divResults`:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)/* && xmlhttp.status==200) */
        {
            document.getElementById("divResults").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            var myDiv = document.getElementById("divResults");
            var myscripz = myDiv.getElementsByTagName('script');
            for(var i=myscripz.length; i--;){
                   eval(myscripz[i].innerHTML);
            }
            result(); //alerts success
}
```

**Easy Way:**

The easiest way i would do it is basically remove the JavaScript from the php and display the content, and after callback just do the rest of the JavaScript within the callback function
php:

```
 echo 'These Are The Results';
```

JavaScript:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)/* && xmlhttp.status==200) */
    {
        document.getElementById("divResults").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        alert('success'); // or whatever else JavaScript you need to do
    }
}
```

Comment: I got it!!! using your code just above the "Easy Way" i was able to get result(); to display the alert!!!!  I just had to echo the javascript from the php instead of display it as html. thank you!! i will work with this (and the other comment to my original post from above)!!

Comment: Grats @Adam happy JavaScripting ;D

Answer (score 0):

try to wrap the javascript code from Result.php in a function and call it after inserting it like :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function result() {
        alert("Success");
    }
</script>
These Are The Results
```

and

```
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)/* && xmlhttp.status==200) */
    {
        document.getElementById("divResults").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        if(result) result();
    }
```

Comment: when i do that, i get a javascript error: 'result' is undefined

Comment: similarly, this would not work because result was never eval(); by the browser

Answer (score 0):

Your results.php needs to be something like...

```
echo 'eval("function results() { alert(\'success\'); }");';
```

And then call the results function.

Comment: I am getting the javascript error message: 'results' is undefined. - - - - - - - Results.php: echo '<script type="text/javascript">eval("function results() { alert(\'success\'); }");</script>';  - - - - - - - - - - - - Main's javasript: document.getElementById("divResults").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;  if(results) results();

Comment: the echo message is still not evaluated by the browser after ajax callback

Comment: Does it need to be a function that is output.
Can you not just echo 'eval("alert(\'success\');")';

Comment: the browser must evaluate the JavaScript on client side. so even if you echo eval its basically just a syntax that the browser have not evaluated yet

Comment: Lol, you're right; I knew what i meant :P
echo 'alert("")'; from the php.
And the ajax call should eval the returned data.

Comment: @David Cooke yep. take a look at my answer and show me some love if you think it deems